# Prove $r^n - s^n = (r-s)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} r^js^{n-j-1}$ by induction

Tags: proof-writing, summation

Prove $$r^n - s^n = (r-s)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} r^js^{n-j-1} $$ $(1)$by induction.

I've verified that $$n=1: r^1 - s^1 = (r-s)(r^0s{1-0-1}) = r-s$$

Assume $(1)$ is true for $n \le k$. That is 
$$r^k - s^k = (r-s)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} r^js^{k-j-1} $$ is true.

$$ n = k + 1: \sum_{j=0}^{(k+1)-1} r^js^{(k+1)-j-1} =\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} r^js^{(k+1)-j-1} + r^k = s\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} r^js^{k-j-1} + r^k \Rightarrow 
(r-s)\sum_{j=0}^{(k+1)-1} r^js^{(k+1)-j-1} = (r-s)(s(r^k-s^k)+r^k)$$ $(2)$

However I cannot write the last expression $(2)$ as $r^{k+1}-s^{k+1}$. Could someone help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You applied your induction hypothesis incorrectly!

You should have $$\begin{aligned} (r-s)\sum_{j=0}^{(k+1)-1} r^js^{(k+1)-j-1} &= (r-s)\left(s\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}r^j s^{k-j-1}} + r^k\right) \\ &= (r-s)\left(s\cdot\frac{\color{green}{r^k-s^k}}{\color{red}{r-s}} +r^k\right)\text{ since }\color{red}{(r-s)}\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}r^j s^{k-j-1}} = \color{green}{r^k-s^k}\\ &= sr^k-s^{k+1} +r^{k+1} -sr^k\\ &= r^{k+1}-s^{k+1}\end{aligned}$$

I hope this clarifies things!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see it now.

Answer (score 3):

Write $t=r/s$. Then $r^n-s^n=s^n(t^n-1)$. It easier to prove by induction that $t^n-1=(t-1)(1+t+t^2+\cdots+t^{n-1})$.